# Find intermediate value of last block

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

A common error during decryption is "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed".

If I am trying to debug what padding the mode the sender is using, how can I access the contents of the last block (including the invalid padding)?

See below a slightly-modified version of the MSDN example for [AesManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using ( MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream( cipherText ) )
{
    using ( CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream( msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read ) )
    {
        using ( StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader( csDecrypt ) )
        {
            try
            {
                plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch ( CryptographicException )
            {
                // ???
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that invalid padding is normally caused by incorrectly encoding the ciphertext or using incorrect key bytes. PKCS#7 padding is starting to be the ad-hoc standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

decrypt with padding mode none (set on your `AesManaged` before `CreateDecryptor()`)